# Scala Functional Programming Generics

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to implement a generic compose combinator

Recall that the composition of two functions—f and g-- is h(x) = f(g(x))

```
    def inc(x: Double) = x + 1
    def double(x: Double) = 2 * x

    def compose[T](f: T, g: T, x: Int) = f(g(x))

    println(compose(double, inc, 2))
```

I'm getting errors no matter what I try to do, I think I have a misunderstanding on generics or passing in functions...

What I want the compose function to do is take in two functions and execute f(g(x)) which would do g(x) first, then f(result of g(x)). In my example the result should be: **2(2+1) = 6**

**Question**: How can I refactor my code to do this?

Comment: You need to specify that f and g are function types.  T could be anything

Comment: Hm makes sense how do i specify that?

Comment: def inc[T <: Number](x: Int) = x + 1
def dbl[T <: Number](x: Int) = 2 * x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to compose the functions, you have to make sure that the types match.

```
def compose[A,B,C](f: B => C, g: A => B, x: A): C = f(g(x))
println(compose(double, inc, 2.toDouble))
```

Then you can compose them.
These combinators are already provided in Scala so you could do:

```
val inc = (v: Double) => v +1
val double = (v: Double) => v * 2
inc.andThen(double)
```

Comment: Your solution works! But I think I do have a misunderstanding on generics. Why do we have to set C = f(g(x))? And the parameters B => C , A => B.. Is there a more simple way to refactor this or is it pretty simplified as is?

Comment: Oh that's not C = f(g(x)), you were defining the type of the function, right?

Comment: if you want to make the function completely generic to any input and output you need to make it generic for the input A, the intermediary state B and the result C, the type parameters in the function are making sure that the output of g is of the same type as the input of f, otherwise it would fail

Comment: > Is there a more simple way to refactor this or is it pretty simplified as is?I don't think so. B => C is just a syntactic sugar for f: Function1[B, C] so you can write it as "def compose[A,B,C](f: Function1[B, C], g: Function1[A, B], x: A): C = return f(g(x))" which is more verbose.